# Visual Studio: Cannot connect to azure mobile project from my xamarin android project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, samsung-mobile

In my visual studio solution, I've 2 projects:

- Xamarin Android
- Azure Mobile Service

I'm not using a emulator, I'm using my android phone for testing.

When I type `http://localhost:55492/tables/todoitem` in the address bar of the browser, I get the sample data:

```
[
 {"id":"784034d4-076c-4bbd-8ec0-72d3c1993c50","complete":false,"text":"First item"},
 {"id":"ae90715d-063b-44b2-916e-97ca8082d436","complete":false,"text":"Second item"}
]
```

I've added this line in the MainActivity:

```
//...
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  byte[] arr = client.DownloadData("http://localhost:55492/tables/todoitem");
  //...
}
```

I'm getting the following error: **Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)**

Is there any reason the connection is being refused?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the IP address of your PC in the server URL, not localhost. Using localhost will cause the phone to try to connect to itself. You can get the IP address by opening a console and running ipconfig on Windows and ifconfig on most other platforms.

Comment: I've replaced localhost with the IP address as follow: `http://10.0.0.4:55492/tables/todoitem`. Now I'm getting a `Timeout Exception`.

Comment: Is your phone connected to the same network as your PC? Connecting android phones via USB doesn't connect them to the same network, they must be connected on wifi as well. Did you open that port on your PC's firewall?

Comment: I've open the port on the firewall and connect my phone to wifi. Now I'm getting: `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`

Comment: This shows that at least you are hitting the backend. Another thing I realized is that you cannot hit IIS Express from a remote machine. Try running the site on full IIS.

Comment: Now I'm running the full IIS. But I'm getting this error now: `Error: ConnectFailure (Connection Refused)`

Comment: Did you update the port in the client to match the port that IIS is running on?